# root last chance to save server (sudoers file broken)

Tags: linux, sudo, root, sudoers, linux-server

I know it's quite dumb to edit the /etc/sudoers file with nano and not visudo, but I did it and got an Syntax error :( .

I have the root password and tried to login, but the root user is set to bin/false in the /etc/passwd file, which means I am currently up the creek without a paddle.

Does anyone know how to manage to get out of this misery? Besides I have no physical access to the server and I login of curse over ssh. In the sshd_config file rootlogin is enabled.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: SSH + normal SU?

Comment: I connected to the server with my normal user and typed in su, then typed in the password, because of the bin/false I am not able to open a bash shell for the root user.

Comment: Wouldn't that give you a root shell? Except that in this case the shell for root is /bin/false, and will thus fail?  But `su -c /usr/local/bin/bash` might just work. (edit, or whatever the path to bash is on linux. Or `su -c visudo' or ...)

Comment: I suggest to try `su - -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: Okay I will try it otherwise I am going to reset it altough I really want to take this point as the last option.

Comment: @Cyrus su - -s /bin/bash did not work. Hennes yours didn't too. Does one of you two have any other suggestions, if so please help me. I really don't want to call the support for my dumb situation, Isn't there any other way to get out of this ? :( edit: I also tried scp to upload a new sudoers file with root, but it does nothing.

Comment: Is your server a desktop, a real server or something virtualised? In the last two cases you should be able to get the same access to the system as if you are sitting behinds it physical keyboard and mice. You might even be able to boot from a CD which really is an iso file on your own desktop. (I know my DRAC in a Dell R300 core2quad era server can do that). If it is virtualised then you might need to ask for this.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have no physical access to the server - someone has. There are many ways but all of them assume you're booting from another partition. For example depending on your hosting provider:

- Ask support to mount the drive to another server
- ask support to put server in rescue mode, usually it means they temporarily load clean OS from another drive and attach your original partition
- Create a snapshot of the drive, restore on another server as secondary drive, edit, create snapshot, restore on original.
- etc

Comment: If it is a server and not a desktop: Remote access (ILO, DRAC, ...). If it a virtualised server: Ditto, but probably need to ask the provider for it.

Comment: Every physical server has a disk which can be taken off. Any virtual server has a logical disk which can be unmounted. Every *good* virtualization system allows you to create a snapshot then restore it.